# Are Beasts immune to the "You Must Obey" Nightmare?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, beast-the-primordial

Situation: the You Must Obey Nightmare (Beast: the Primordial, p. 138) functions similarly to the Dominate Discipline of a Ventrue vampire, but instead of hypnotizing the target (inflicting the Mesmerized condition), the target is fully aware of what's going on, but can't resist without suffering a Breaking Point, unlike a Dominated individual who only wakes up if hit or *after doing something that caused a Breaking Point* (VtR 2e, p. 305).

In other words, Dominate hypnotizes people into going along with whatever is said until they wake up and freak out. You Must Obey says, "Do what I say, or you get a swat on the sanity," and the target gets the "choice" of whether or not they want to comply.

Problem: Beasts, by nature, have no Integrity equivalent. Their feeding patterns and very existences cause sanity loss in other people. As such, they don't suffer Breaking Points.

So, if I haven't missed anything in the text that says, "If a beast encounters a Breaking Point, roll Satiety," or something to that effect, does that mean that, unlike just about all of the other Nightmares, You Must Obey, RAW, doesn't hinder other beasts? Can they just ignore the commands unless the user spent Satiety to help them regain Willpower and get Exceptional Successes easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember this being bought up on the onyx path forums a few years ago.

**RAW Beasts do not suffer breaking points. They are therefore immune. This extends to all other creatures that can not suffer breaking points such as Beshilu hosts from Werewolf.**

Quickly the reasons for this are all to do with Satiety. In many ways Satiety is similar to Integrity or the secondary traits which are also known as advantage traits in other lines, Harmony in Werewolf, Cover in Demon, clarity in changeling, etc are all in this family of stat, they all provide a gauge for how human or not a character is compared to where they are as whatever supernatural they are.

Satiety and the begotten are unique as the only things that modify this stat originates from themselves by feeding, using abilities and maintaining lairs. It is less a measure of wellbeing, morality or humanity as it is a exploitable resource and sustenance for the beasts existence.

Satiety can explicitly not be modified through degeneration rolls or breaking points. It's another way beast the primordial can feel different to other Chronicle of Darkness games in the line.